# How get variable type?

Tags: java, android

In my application I have two textfield and one submit. This app calculate integer value in this textfiels. But if I put there text - have error. How I can check this text field for int and how show message if thare no integers. My try:

```
EditText num1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num1text);
EditText num2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.num2text);        
Float num1=Float.parseFloat(num1text.getText().toString());
Float num2=Float.parseFloat(num2text.getText().toString());

if (num1 instanceof Float && num2 instanceof Float)
{
Float answ = (num1 * num2) / 100;
TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
answer.setText(answ);
}else
answer.setText("Message");
```

But my app still don't show my message in else case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As some others commented, you can use a regular expression to check the contents of the input field before you start converting them. This a good recommendation, you should scrub any user inputs before use.

If you don't, or can't: the `Float.parseFloat()` operation throws `NumberFormatException` if the input cannot be converted. You need to use a `try...catch` construct to avoid this.

```
try {
    Float num1=Float.parseFloat(num1text.getText().toString());
    Float num2=Float.parseFloat(num2text.getText().toString());
    Float answ = (num1 * num2) / 100;
    TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
    answer.setText(answ);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    TextView answer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.ans);
    answer.setText("Message");
}
```

Furthermore, you can use the `android:inputType` attribute in your layout XML to restrict the input to numbers only (and get a numeric keyboard).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a regular expression:

```
if (YourVariable.matches("^[0-9,;]+$")) {
    // Contains only numbers
} else {
    // Contains NOT only numbers
}
```

Comment: I can't use this for Float

Answer (score 0):

If the input was fixed that you have to need always integer/real (Number) value then you can set the `inputtype` in your xml file for `EditText` as attribute to number.

This will softkeyboard show only number keys on screen so you can getting always the number and no need to check for type whether user enter Character or Number value

For e.g. like this

```
<EditText android:inputType="number"
.../>
```

Answer (score 0):

Float.parseFloat(num2text.getText().toString()); if not float throws a number format exception. Catch the exception. Clear the fields. Display a toast message that the input is invalid.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView answer;
EditText num1text,num2text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    num1text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    num2text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);   
    Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
            Float num2=Float.parseFloat(num2text.getText().toString());
            Float num1=Float.parseFloat(num1text.getText().toString());
                            //if the numbers are not float throws a numberformat exception
            if (num1 instanceof Float && num2 instanceof Float)
            {
            Float answ = (num1 * num2) / 100;
            answer.setText(Float.toString(answ));
            }else
            answer.setText("Message");
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                               //catch the exception clear the fields and display toast
                num1text.setText("");
                num2text.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid Input Type!Check the input", 1000).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });

}
}
```